# How to use variable as type in C#

Tags: c#, types

I have got some code where I want to use variable as type:

```cs
public static void SaveData(string table, DataTable data, string connectionString)
{

    List<Col> columns = new List<Col>();

    DataTable dataInDB = SqlOperations.GetData(table, connectionString).Tables[0];

    foreach (DataColumn name in data.Columns)
    {
        columns.Add(new Col() { name = name.ColumnName, typ = name.DataType});
    }

    foreach (DataRow SourceRow in data.Rows)
    {
        Type t = columns.First().typ;
        DataTable selectyRow = dataInDB.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<t>(columns.First().name));
        for (int i = 1; i < columns.Count; i++)
        {

        }
    }
}

private struct Col
{
   public string name;
    public Type typ;
}
```

Debugger said that "t is variable but use as a type". How use this as type?

Comment: You can't - the point about variable types is that the compiler knows about them *at compile-time*. Unfortunately we don't know what you're attempting to do with this type, which makes it hard to suggest an alternative. (As an aside, I'd generally suggest avoiding mutable structs and public fields.)

Comment: So od it isn't posible to dynamicly type, will be able to make something like this: x.Field<var>(columns.First().name)?

Comment: What is `.Where(x => x.Field<t>(columns.First().name))` supposed to do? The non-generic version would be:  `.Where(x => x.Item[columns.First().name])` but unless that column is a boolean column, it makes no sense for a `Where` clause.

Comment: This code it isn't finished yet. IT will compare if data column on database with value on DataTable

Comment: OK try using `Item[]` instead of `Field<T>()` and `Equals` instead of `==` and see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use a variable as a type.
Since variables are so, variables, you are not providing any information to the compiler.

May be, you could solve this by using reflection.

```
...
DataTable table = data.AsEnumerable().Where(x => CheckData(x, t, columns.First().name));
...
```

Then use reflection to invoke the generic method.

```
public bool CheckData(DataRow x, Type t, params object[] args)
{
    MethodInfo method = x.GetType().GetMethod("Field");
    MethodInfo genric = method.MakeGenericMethod(t);

    return (bool) genric.Invoke(c, args);
}
```

Comment: 1) Why create a generic method using reflection when there's a non-generic one available (`Item`), and 2) `Field` is an _extension method_, not a method on `DataRow` so this reflection code will fail.

Comment: Well.
I am providing a solution to the question "How to use variable as a type?", which was the post. Not trying to solve his detailed problem. I don't really know about those types, indeed.